# Base Ubuntu Server, Can't install anything

Tags: server, apt, package-management, apache2, lamp

I'm currently administrating an Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 and was looking forward to installing LAMP, first two lines I wrote were

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists.. Done (no more no less)

$ sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Only to get "unable to locate package apache2", how do I deal with that? and will I keep running into this for all repositories?

Comment: Does the `apt-get update` command terminate?

Comment: Yes, it just prints one line and it goes back to cursor

Comment: Please add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: It's just an empty file

Comment: Are there any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, if it exists? If yes, add them to your question.

Comment: no, empty folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I take from our conversation in the comments, you have no software sources configured. This can be due to the following reasons:

- No sources were configured on installation. (is this even possible?)
- The software sources were removed accidentally or maliciously deliberately.
- They were lost due to another reason, which would most likely indicate a system that is broken elsewise, too.

---

If your system has a GUI installed, you can open the *Software Sources* utility (if it is installed). If it isn't or your system doesn't have a graphical desktop, you can generate a new sources list using tools like the [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/).

Select your country (for mirror selection) and Trusty as release, and then enable the repositories you wish to have (at least *main* and *universe*). Then tool will generate a text output, which you can copy and paste into the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or save it to a local file and upload it to the server. Then your APT commands should work again.

Comment: what if I don't have gui, just a base server? Thanks

Comment: How do you access server terminals? Physical keyboard attached to the server? SSH?

Comment: I access it using SSH

Comment: Then generate and save the sources.list on the ssh client and then move it to the server using SCP or SFTP, or open an text editor from the server (e.g. nano, emacs or vim) over ssh on the client and paste the contents there.